# Can't run migrations when setting up a project with cookiecutter-django

Tags: python, django, cookiecutter-django

I have been trying to set up a new django project locally with cookiecutter-django. I have followed the docs but I keep getting into errors when trying to run `python manage.py migrate`.

Error Traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/ubuntu/lasbrisas_project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/ubuntu/lasbrisas_project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 302, in execute
settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "/home/ubuntu/lasbrisas_project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/home/ubuntu/lasbrisas_project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/home/ubuntu/lasbrisas_project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/home/ubuntu/lasbrisas_project/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/ubuntu/lasbrisas_project/django_condominios/config/settings/local.py", line 11, in <module>
from .common import *  # noqa
File "/home/ubuntu/lasbrisas_project/django_condominios/config/settings/common.py", line 102, in <module>
'default': env.db('DATABASE_URL', default='postgres:///django_condominios'),
File "/home/ubuntu/lasbrisas_project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 180, in db_url
return self.db_url_config(self.get_value(var, default=default), engine=engine)
File "/home/ubuntu/lasbrisas_project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 371, in db_url_config
'PORT': _cast_int(url.port),
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/parse.py", line 156, in port
port = int(port, 10)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'jd#uhUhey385'
```

I don't really know what I am doing wrong while setting up the project, I'd appreciate if you check the steps I took and help me find out what is missing.

**Steps taken to setup the project with cookiecutter-django:**

*pip, virtualenv, PostrgreSQL already installed*

1. `pip install cookiecutter`
2. `cookiecutter https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django`
3. Answer cookiecutter questions
4. Creating virtualenv - `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 venv`
5. Activiting virtualenv - `source venv/bin/activate/`
6. `cd intoprojectfolder`
7. Docs say `sudo ./install_os_dependencies.sh install` but ./install_os_dependencies.sh is not in projectroot, file found in utility/

   - `cd utility`
   - `sudo ./install_os_dependencies.sh install`
8. `pip install -r requirements/local.txt`
9. Setting up db in postgresql:

   - `sudo su - postgres`
   - `psql`
   - `CREATE DATABASE myproject;`
   - `CREATE USER myprojectuser WITH PASSWORD 'password';`
   - `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE myproject TO myprojectuser;`
   - `\q`
10. Return tu project root
11. `mv env.example .env`
12. `export DATABASE_URL=postgres://myprojectuser:myprojectuserdbpassword@127.0.0.1:5432/myproject`
13. `python manage.py migrate`

After that is when I get the traceback, what could be going wrong? The docs show no more information, the migration should work.

Comment: you should run `createdb slugofprojectname` because that is the db cookiecutter is expecting to find.

Answer (score 2):

Cookiecutter uses the slug of the project name as the name for the development db you are to use. You are expected to create the database yourself.

from your stacktrace here is the line giving you the problem from your settings.py file:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/lasbrisas_project/django_condominios/config/settings/common.py", line 102, in <module>'default': env.db('DATABASE_URL',     default='postgres:///django_condominios'),
```

It expects to find a database named *django_condominios*.

You can fix this by running

```
createdb django_condominios
```

and you should be good run your migrations.

Comment: i created the db myself (step 9 of the OP), and named it using the slug as the documentation suggested.

Comment: Can you search for this string in the whole project " 'jd#uhUhey38". An integer value is expected there,not a string.

Comment: It is part of the DB_URL its the db password `export DATABASE_URL=postgres://myprojectuser:jd#uhUhey38@127.0.0.1:5432/myproject`